# How to use Linux Xampp mysql_pdo with Symfony 2.0

Tags: mysql, pdo, xampp, doctrine-orm, symfony

I've got a serious problem.
I would like to use Doctrine 2 on my Symfony 2 projet.

I've change the php path from the app/console :

```
/opt/lampp/bin php
```

I've specify the good path for my mysql_pdo in /opt/lampp/etc/php.ini

```
pdo_mysql.default_socket = /opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

and check to my php_info() for my pdo :

> ```
> PDO
>
> PDO support   enabled
> PDO drivers   mysql, pgsql, sqlite, sqlite2
>
> pdo_mysql
>
> PDO Driver for MySQL  enabled
> Client API version    mysqlnd 5.0.7-dev - 091210 - $Revision: 304625
> ```
>
> $
>
> ```
> Directive Local Value Master Value
> ```
>
> pdo_mysql.default_socket  /opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock /opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock
>
> ```
> pdo_pgsql
>
> PDO Driver for PostgreSQL enabled
> PostgreSQL(libpq) Version 8.0.3
> Module version    1.0.2
> Revision   $Id: pdo_pgsql.c 300351 2010-06-10 12:11:19Z iliaa $
> ```

Everything seems fine, but when I use this Symfony command :

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:import WonderWBundle yml
```

It juste says :

> [PDOException]            could not find driver

I'm on Ubuntu 10.10
 XAMPP for Linux 1.7.4 !

It seems that I've got everything to made Pdo work well but not on Symfony 2.
Does anyone could help ? Pleeeaaaassse (I'm going mad !!)

Thanks a lot :P

(P.S : Grrr cannot link my screenshots !)

Comment: I've got my answer !
Ok, one tricky thing !
My first step was the good one ! You can Follow it there >> http://antoine.goutenoir.com/blog/2011/02/12/use-symfony2-console-with-lampp-without-installing-php-package-under-ubuntu-or-debian/ <<

BUT ... NEVER USER php  app/console after that ! That doesn't work !
Instead just a sudo app/console is enough !
(Hop they would notify this somewhere :P)

Answer (score 1):

Another reason could be related to PHP itself.
Various linux distros compile their `php-cgi/fpm/apache` and `php-cli` to use different `php.ini` files ( which actually makes sense )

Both ini files use to have their module configuration files included from subdirectories.
If you install an additional module manually, the `phpinfo()?  viewed in a web browser may show the module, but programs executed on the commandline, just like Zend Framework app/console are using php-cli with another configuration.

e.g. for the apache module

```
/etc/php/php-apache/php.ini 
/etc/php/php-apache/php.d/pdo_mysql.ini
```

for the commandline php

```
/etc/php/php-cli/php.ini
```

In this case you have to repeat your module configuration for the commandline client

```
/etc/php/php-cli/php.d/pdo_mysql.ini
```

The commandline php also has a `phpinfo` functionality, which you can use to verify your cli installation:

```
~ # php -i | grep "pdo"
```